# How do I contribute a version of the same module for the latest core version?

Tags: community-official-site

I have contributed a module for Drupal 7; now I am interested in contributing the Drupal 8 version of the same module.

When I started creating the Drupal 7 version; I had all the instructions (under VERSION CONTROL of the project); now I need instructions in order to start with the Drupal 8 of the module.

So, I am looking for GIT instructions.

Comment: There is no specific git instructions for Drupal 8.... What you should do is to create a 8.x branch.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal.org apparently doesn't give information for Drupal 8, in the *Version control* tab of projects. I checked for a project with a Drupal 8 version (the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module), but even selecting a Drupal 8 branch, the information given is for Drupal 7.

That said, there isn't much difference, with Drupal 8. What I report here are the adapted instructions for Drupal 8.

> ### Creating Releases
>
> See the [naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1015226) for a complete description of how to name branches and tags so you can create releases.
>
> #### Branch for a dev release
>
> This creates and checks out a new branch in one command, then pushes it to Drupal.org.
>
> ```
> git checkout -b 8.x-1.x
> git push -u origin 8.x-1.x
> ```
>
> #### Tag for a stable release
>
> ```
> git checkout  8.x-1.x
> git tag 8.x-1.0
> git push origin tag 8.x-1.0
> ```